# List is returning each object as string type, but breaks when I try to convert it to int

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write some code to take a multiplication factor and some vectors, then multiplying them together. I am able to run the math, and the code is working, but when I enter my vector, it will only be accepted as a string. For example, if my factor is 5, and the vector is 1 2, then I get 11111 22222. I understand this is because the code is reading my vector input as a string, but if I ever put the vector list in an int() function, my code will break there. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
mult_factor = int(input("What number do you want some vectors multiplied by? "))
vector_input = input("Enter the vectors you want to be multiplied ")

vector_string = vector_input.split()


def scalar_mult(mult, vect):
    scalar_list = [i * mult for i in vect]
    return scalar_list

answer = scalar_mult(mult_factor, vector_string)
print(answer)
```

Comment: Try: `vector_string = [int(i) for i in vector_input.split()]` or `vector_string = list(map(int, vector_input.split()))` to turn your strings into ints before you start.

Comment: @Loocid Yes, the second one worked, at least! Thank you